# How to batch rename files but not directories?

Tags: batch-rename

I have lots of files that need an extension appended to them but they are in a directory with lots of subdirectories. Currently the files have no extension at all. How would I rename just the files but not rename any of the directories or subdirectories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate all and test whether it's a regular file or not.

```
#bash
for file in ./*; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && mv "$file" "$file.ext"
done
```

In case you need to avoid adding extension on files that already have it:

```
for file in ./*; do
    if [[ -f $file && $file != *.ext ]]; then
        mv "$file" "$file.ext"
    fi
done
```

Comment: For some reason this script ignores file names that include spaces in them, is there anyway to include them as well?

Comment: @Kevin, it should handle them just fine. Did you modify anything? If you remove any of the `"`-quotes, it will fail on filenames containing whitespace or other syntactical characters.

Comment: @geirha shouldn't -f $file have quotes as well ?

Comment: @Serg With `[ ... ]` instead, then quotes would be necessary, but `[[ ... ]]` is a shell keyword and is parsed differently, so quotes there are optional. See [BashFAQ 31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for more on the differences.